# How to align php search results displayed?

Tags: php, mysql, html

How do I align and put div tags around the displayed data? I am very new to php and hope you guys can help!

Thanks!

James

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("", "", "");

if (!$conn) {
echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

{

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

}

if (!mysql_select_db("")) {
echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT name,lastname,email 
FROM   test_mysql
WHERE  name LIKE '$search%' AND lastname LIKE '$searchterm'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row["name"];
echo $row["lastname"];
echo $row["email"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>

<?php echo $row["name"];?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["lastname"];?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["email"];?>
```

Comment: This has more to do with HTML and CSS than with PHP. For tabular data needing alignment, I suggest using `table`. If you go for using `div`s, refer to CSS documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo '<div class="data">';
   echo '<label>' . $row["name"] . '</label>';
   echo '<label>' . $row["lastname"] . '</label>';
   echo '<label>' . $row["email"] . '</label>';
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Anyway I don't understand the need to have this:

```
<?php echo $row["name"];?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["lastname"];?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["email"];?>
```

which will never echo nothing (will always echo the empty string) because when the script reaches this code, `$row = false`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! What I mean is all i want to do is to be able to add div tags around each row how is this done?

Comment: Ah thanks it works but the <br> tag doesn't. How can i make each row on a different line?

Comment: What rows? Those in the while or after? Have you read my advice on the echo after the while?

Comment: i got rid of the ones that aren't in the while. But yeah the <br> tag doenst work on those in the while?

Comment: You have to chance: 1) Change this line echo '</div>'; into this echo '</div><br /><br />'; 2) **The better one** Using CSS, put this rule .data{margin-bottom: 10px;}

Comment: I used the margin feature but still no change. the results are all in a line on the same line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4498/discussion-between-aurelioderosa-and-james)